# mpc85xx(P2040) startup using Nor Flash, where is Nor Flash mapped to?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bootloader, powerpc, u-boot

I'm porting u-boot to P2040 based board these days.

As u-boot/arch/powerpc/mpc85xx/start.s commented:
The processor starts at 0xffff_fffc and the code is first executed in the last 4K page in flash/rom.

In u-boot/arch/powerpc/mpc85xx/resetvec.S:

```
.section .resetvec,"ax"
b _start_e500
```

And in u-boot.lds linker script:

```
.resetvec RESET_VECTOR_ADDRESS :
{
     KEEP(*(.resetvec))
} :text = 0xffff
```

The reset vector is at 0xffff_fffc, which contains a jump instruction to _start_e500.

The E500MCRM Chapter 6.6 mentioned:
This default TLB entry translates the first instruction fetch out of reset(at effective address 0xffff_fffc).
This instruction should be a branch to the beginning of this page.

So, if I configure the HCW to let powerpc boot from Nor Flash, why should I suppose that the Nor Flash's
last 4K is mapped to 0xffff_f000~0xffff_ffff? Since there're no LAW setup yet and the default BR0/OR0 of Local Bus
does not match that range. I’m confused about how Nor Flash be access at the very beginning of core startup.

Another question is:
Does P2040 always have MMU enabled so as to translate effective address to real address even at u-boot stage?
If so, beside accessing to CCSRBAR, all other memory access should have TLB entry setup first.

Best Regards,
Hook Guo

Comment: Read the UM again. And read (u-boot 2014.xx latest) arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/start.S starting at line 60.

Comment: Hi @sessyargc.jp, I do noticed that comments in start.S. But I'm still confused. The UM says: the 8Mbytes boot window is valid at core startup, and it's from 0xffc0_0000 to 0xffff_ffff. But why should I suppose that range is Nor Flash? Why is the .bootpg section located at the LAST page, which is mapped by MMU L2 TLB1 Entry0?

Comment: Watch your addresses, 0xfffc0000 is not 8Mb. AFAIK, HW sets this boot window to NOR Flash initially. You can change it by modifying your RCW. You should look at "Boot Space Translation" in the Reference Manual and "Instruction Flow" in the E500CORERM.pdf. bootpg is always in the last 4Kb because that is the only page available after core reset. HW sets that up, but HW can only do so much. So the code in the last 4Kb us important. As you will notice it sets up the TLBs and LAWs.

Comment: Thanks for your help @sessyargc.jp. By saying "HW sets this boot window to NOR Flash initially", do you mean: it's the pre-bootloader that use PBL commands to set boot window to Nor Flash?

Comment: Hi @sessyargc.jp, I think I'm nearly get the point. When RCW set eLBC GPCM Nor Flash 16-bit as booting ROM, the Boot Window is pointed to eLBC, and processor starts at 0xFFFF_FFFC, the real address is mapped to last 2 words of Nor Flash. (As P2040RM 13.4.2 mentioned: On system reset, a global chip-select is available that provides a boot ROM chip-select LCS0_B prior to the system being fully configured). The last 2 words of Nor Flash is a branch instruction to _start_e500, which is at the start of .bootpg. Codes in .bootpg section setup more TLB entry to make reset of u-boot code take effect.

Comment: Is this your first time working on the PowerPC? This specific core (as well as other Freescale cores) always starts at 0xffff_fffc. The HW always makes sure that NOR is mapped to this region. PBL is not needed to map NOR Flash to the boot window. It happens all in HW automagically. You can alter this behaviour by using RCW + PBI image to boot from SPI NOR, for example. The linker script makes sure the instruction at 0xffff_fffc is always jump to to top of the last 4Kb.

Comment: Only this year Am I start working on PowerPC low level programming. Need more effort to make many things clear. I appreciate your generous help @sessyargc.jp! Thank you buddy!